# Twitter bootstrap with ASP.NET not MVC

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working in ASP.NET Web Applications (not MVC) for a while at work. I really would like to use the twitter bootstrap framwork. I think it looks great and has a lot of the work already taken care of for you. I cannot seem to get it to work with ASP server controls. I know that the css is probably trying to change the asp:Button tag to an HTML tag. I just have no idea how to get these to work together. I get the following error.

Warning 2   //file location : ASP.NET runtime error: The base class includes the field 'btnTest', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button).   //File location 21  1   FalconFutbolClub

When rendering the site to debug, I get the following error:

Control 'mainContentHolder_btnTest' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

I think it would be really annoying to try to manage postbacks with javascript. I really would just like to use regular ASP server controls, hence the whole reason of using ASP.NET Web Applications. Please help.

EDIT: Code. Here is the master page and my default.

Master Asp:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs"           Inherits="FalconFutbolClub.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Falcon Futbol</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="What's in your toybox?">
    <meta name="author" content="Pure Parties">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 85px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headerContentHolder" runat="server" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Falcon Futbol</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div span="12">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContentHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    })
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Master C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FalconFutbolClub
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Default aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headerContentHolder" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentHolder" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="jumbotron subhead" id="overview">
            <h1>Falcon Futbol</h1>
            <p>Event registration forms can be filled out here.</p>
            <asp:Label ID="clickedTest" runat="server" />
        </header>
        <div class="span12">
            <blockquote>
                <p>Event registration form 1.</p>
                <small>March 17, 2012</small>
            </blockquote>
            <div class="span4">
                <asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="btnForm1_Click" Text="test" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Default C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace FalconFutbolClub
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clickedTest.Text = "Clicked!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That error that you have quoted must be related to something else, not Bootstrap. It might be more beneficial of you posted the code.

Comment: I added the master and default pages here with my test code. This throws the error.

Comment: wow....after typing all of that in....i realized...i didnt have a <form> tag....wow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you answered this yourself!  Just to follow up on it - normally just after the body tag of a masterpage you would have a form tag:

```
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
       <!-- omitted code from above -->
     </div>
  </div>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I noticed afterwards that I am an idiot and forgot this. Super embarassing. Thank you for the response.